# After going through convolution steps, what should be the shape of the tensor in fully connected layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So let's assume that I have RGB images of shape `[128,128,3]`, I want to create a CNN with two Conv-ReLu-MaxPool layers as below.

```
def cnn(input_data):

    #conv1
    conv1_weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,4,3,25], stddev=0.1,),tf.float32)
    conv1_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]), tf.float32)

    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_data, conv1_weight, [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.add(conv1, conv1_bias))
    max_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, [1,2,2,1], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')

    #conv2
    conv2_weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,4,25,50]),0.1,tf.float32)
    conv2_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([50]), tf.float32)

    conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(max_pool1, conv2_weight, [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    relu2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.add(conv2, conv2_bias))
    max_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, [1,2,2,1], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
```

After this step, I need to transform the output into 1xN layer for the next fully connected layer. However, I am not sure how I should determine what N is in 1xN. Is there a specific formula including the layer size, strides, max pool size, image size etc? I am pretty lost in this phase of the problem even though I think that I get the intuition behind a CNN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to transform the multiple 2D feature maps that come out of the last convolutional/pooling layer to a vector that can be fed into a fully-connected layer. Or to be precise and include the batch dimension,  go from shape `[batch, width, height, feature_maps]` to `[batch, N]`.

The above already implies that `N = batch * width * height` since reshaping keeps the overall number of elements the same. `width` and `height` depend on the size of your inputs and the strides of your network layers (convolution and/or pooling).
A stride of `x` simply divides the size by `x`. You have inputs of size 128 in each dimension, and two pooling layers with stride 2. Thus after the first pooling layer your images are 64x64 and after the second they are 32x32, so `width = height = 32`. Normally we would have to account for padding as well but the point of `SAME` padding is precisely that we *don't* have to worry about that.
Finally, `feature_maps` is 50 since that is how many filters your last convolutional layer has (pooling doesn't modify this). So `N = 32*32*50 = 51200`.

Thus, you should be able to do `tf.reshape(max_pool2, [-1, 51200])` (or `tf.reshape(max_pool2, [-1, 32*32*50])` to keep it more interpretable) and feed the resulting 2D tensor through a fully-connected layer (i.e. `tf.matmul`).

The simplest way would be to just use `tf.layers.flatten(max_pool2)`. This function does all the above for you and just gives you the `[batch, N]` result.

Comment: This is gold worthy. Thanks. However I am confused about the pooling part. If I choose to keep padding `SAME`, doesn't it preserve the shape of the output by adding zeros? Or is your answer assuming that we don't use the `SAME` option? What would be the difference in calculating `N` with and without `SAME` padding?

Comment: Padding applies before strides. Without padding (also called "valid" padding), an image of size n (in one dimension) and a filter of size k would produce an output of size n - k + 1. "Same" padding adds k-1 zeroes to the image so that the result has size n (n - k + 1 + k -1).  
If you are using strides (as in your max pooling layers), this will still reduce the output size by a factor (2 in your case). Stride + "same" padding just means the output size is n/2 and not (n - k + 1)/2.

Comment: I am also curious, is it possible to extract the shape out of the tensor we get from `tf.layers.flatten()`? If not, I would have to do the calculation still, because I need it for fully connected layers' weight matrix.

Comment: Assuming the input images have a constant size (I guess they do, 128x128) you should be able to get this via `result.shape[1]` where `result = flatten(...)`. If this doesn't work it might be `result.shape.as_list()[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all since you are starting out, I would recommend Keras instead of pure tensorflow. And to answer your question regarding the shape refer this [blog](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) by Andrej karpathy

### Quote from the blog:

**We can compute the spatial size of the output volume as a function of the input volume size (W), the receptive field size of the Conv Layer neurons (F), the stride with which they are applied (S), and the amount of zero padding used (P) on the border. You can convince yourself that the correct formula for calculating how many neurons “fit” is given by (W−F+2P)/S+1. For example for a 7x7 input and a 3x3 filter with stride 1 and pad 0 we would get a 5x5 output. With stride 2 we would get a 3x3 output.**

### Now coming to your tensorflow's implementation:

For the conv1 stage you have given a 4*4 filter having a depth of 25. Since you have used padding="SAME" for conv1 and maxpooling1 your output 2D spatial dimensions will be same as input for both the cases. That is after conv1 your output size is: 128*128*25. For the same reason the output of your maxpool1 layer is also the same. Since you have given padding to be "SAME" for the second conv2 also your output shape is 128*128*50(you changed the output channels). Thus after maxpool2 your dimensions are: batch_size, 128*128*50. Thus before adding Dense layer you have 3 major options:

1) flatten the tensor results in a shape : batch_size, 128*128*50

2) global average pooling results in a shape : batch_size, 50

3) global max pooling also results in a shape : batch_size, 50.

#### Note:

global average pooling layer is similar to average pooling but, we average the entire feature map instead of a window. Hence the name global. For example: in your case you have batch_size, 128,128,50 as your dimensions. This means you have 50 feature maps with spatial dimensions 128*128. What global average pooling does is that, it 
Averages the 128*128 feature map to give a single number. Thus you will have 50 values in total. This is very useful in designing fully convolutional architectures like inception, resnet etc. Because, this makes the network's input generic meaning you can send any image size as input to the network. Global max pooling is very similar to above but the slight difference is it finds the max value of the feature map instead of average.

### Problems with this architecture:

Generally it is not recommended to use padding = "SAME" in maxpooling layers. If you see the source code of vgg16 you will see that after each block (conv relu and maxpooling) the input size is halved. Thus the general structure is you reduce the spatial dimension while increasing the depth/channels.

Comment: I didn't know that padding = "SAME" in pooling was not recommended. Great to know. Your explanation is very insightful. However I could not understand about the second and the third options you have provided before adding Dense layer.

Comment: I worded it wrong. I didn't mean padding=SAME is not recommended. What I meant was you should make sure that your spatial dimensions reduce uniformly with every block. Thus using padding=same everywhere is not recommended. Generally what people do is, use same padding for conv layers and use no padding in max pooling. Thus the spatial dimensions decreases. I have edited my answer for your next question

Answer (score 0):

Flattening the layer:

```
var_name = tf.layers.flatten(max_pool2)
```

Should work, and it's what almost every example of a Tensorflow CNN uses.

Comment: The question is asking for an explanation of how to compute the flatten dimension, not the command. Hence `how I should determine what N is in 1xN`